# zsh: command not found: create-react-app on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu

I can't get react work on Ubuntu, I just get command not found, can't fix it.

npm install -g create-react-app
/home/name/.npm-global/bin/create-react-app -> /home/name/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
+ create-react-app@1.4.0
updated 1 package in 4.61s

after that I enter:

create-react-app app
zsh: command not found: create-react-app

.zshrc file

export PATH=$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH

I understand that obviously is in path problem, but I can't figure it out, I have some experience with Linux, but I just can't fix this and to get react work.

Thanks.

Ubuntu 17.04
node v8.4.0
npm v5.3.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you need to add `~/.npm-global/bin/` to your `$PATH`:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin/:$HOME/.node_modules_global/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I have Ubuntu in virtualbox, can I use create-react-app in shared folders somehow? Because I saw that it is problem with shared folders because of symlink.

Comment: @MarijanMilovec it seems to me that as long as you set the correct `$PATH`, you can also install it in a shared folder.